# Is using store to get my data instead of data binding between components considered a bad practice?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my current setup, the main business logic is inside selectors and effects and if a component needs some data it can start an action to query the data then get the data through selectors. I'm not using the data binding to pass anything from component to component except when I use `*ngFor`. Is it considered bad practice? Would it be better if I only communicate with the store in the "page components" (which are loaded through the router so they are kind of the page containers)? Will my setup makes testing harder or it's fine? If yes, where should I put my business logic instead?

Comment: Yes best practice is to call the selectors within the container component and pass the values as input to childs. Don't select the same value in every child

Comment: But wouldn't that make the code more cluttered? I mean the container component would be full of "just getting this value from the store and passing it to children" stuff

Comment: Depends. Try to get a feeling when which is more useful. But as a rule of thumb, if a child has only the scope of displaying data (no business logic), then it shouldn't subscribe itself. Prefer an input in that case.

Comment: Awesome! Could you make an answer to this question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get a feeling when which is more useful. But as a rule of thumb, if a child has only the scope of displaying data (no business logic), then it shouldn't subscribe itself. Prefer an input in that case.